# no commit button in Team menu in eclipse when checking out project from github

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, commit

I create a local maven project in eclipse. I share the project on github remote repository. and the Team menu comes to have a list of buttons like commit, revert etc. Just like using svn.

Now I checked out the same project from the same remote repository on another machine. The project was checked out successfully but the Team menu has only Share button. Eclipse dose not recognize it is checked out from a scm.

What to do to make eclipse has the list of buttons in Team menu when checking out a git project?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you have not installed the egit plugin on the second machine, therefore Eclipse doesn't know anything about git repositories.